# jqGrid getRowData not working

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid

I have been trying to retrieve data from jqGrid when I double click but with no success. I am able to get the row Id.  Please can anyone help check this code for me and let me know what is wrong.

```
$(function(){
              $("#itemlist").jqGrid({
                    url:urld,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    colNames:['Subscriber Id','Subscriber Name','Contact Person','Contact Email','Telephone'],
                    colModel :[ 
                      {name:'id', index:'id', width:100,sortable:true}, 
                      {name:'subscribername', index:'subscribername', width:300,sortable:true},
                      {name:'contactperson', index:'contactperson', width:200,sortable:true},
                      {name:'contactemail', index:'contactemail', width:200,sortable:true},
                      {name:'telephone', index:'telephone', width:100,sortable:true}
                    ],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    pgbuttons:true,
                    rowList:[10,20,30],
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    height: 'auto',
                    altRows:true,
                    altclass: 'oddRow',
                    caption: 'Subscriber',
                    ondblClickRow: function(id,iRow,icCol,e)
                    {
                        alert(iRow);
                         var rowData = jQuery("#itemlist").jqGrid('getRowData',iRow);
                        var subName = rowData['subscribername');
alert(subName);

                     }
                  }); 
            });
```

The alert display the iRow but does not display subName.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ondblClickRow: function(id,iRow,icCol,e)
                    {
                        alert(iRow);
                         var rowData = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData',id);
...
```

You were using `iRow` and not the rowID of 'id`. For clarity (though it shouldn't matter really) may I recommend your ondblClickRow be labeled as such:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
```